# how and where to efficiently store and retrieve data every second for this situation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, read-write

hi experts :) I'm using wpf with sql server

problem 1: lots of data gets created and must be saved to db every second, but at the same time multiple parts of the program write to the same tables. Saving to the db every second is not efficient as db methods are expensive, do you experts disagree or what should I do? not sure what is the best thing to do, when would xml or text files be more useful?

problem 2: I have to retrieve the data from the db from the tables that problem 1 is saving to so I can show on live graphs. Would this cause read/write problems?

Comment: I had a db class, sent the item to write to a queue, and every x dumped the queue to the db as a transaction. Problem then is you cant really view completely live data, its always upto x behind.

Comment: I remove the tag WPF since the question has nothing to do with WPF

Answer (score 1):

1. Loading a lot of data with one-by-one `inserts` is not a good idea. Try to look at [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28VS.80%29.aspx)
2. Database handles concurrency very well, you can insulate the writing in proper transaction in order to see just the data when a complete write is done.

Comment: thanks. I am using linq to sql, but I am used to having single inserts. Even if I have a list of 100 items and save that to the db it will still be single inserts. Is there a way to save a list of items in bulk using linq to sql?

Comment: @user1622488 as far as I know, not directly.

Answer (score 0):

1 You can use `Caching` in order to persist your datas, you can save with `Cache` class

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx

2 You don't have problem with second scenario, you can use Transaction in order to ensure that you get commited datas.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have time limit, you have to *process* data in some way in 1 second.

I would suggest:

**problem 1**: Save the data you generate in *chunks* injectd into the `Stack<..>`. After from another thread process that `Stack<..>` to save the *chunk* to the DB, untill the `Stack<..>` is not empty. As there is *no any gurantee* that you wil be able save data in 1 second, after you have it in memory.

**problem 2**: Having it already in memory you can achieve maximum possible perforance, remaining in the acceptable allocated memory limimts.

It's hard to suggest somethign really practical here, as performance is *always* strictly domain specific, which can not be described completely in short question. But soluton, can be taken like a basic guideline.

Answer (score 0):

An other option, is to break up the table(s).

Are your other functions only writing to subset of the field of the records.

So you have a 1 to 1 mapping between two tables one for the initial data, the other for functionA. Depends on how well you can partition the backend needs, but it can significantly reduce collisions.

Basic idea is to look at your tables more like objects. So you have a base table, then if it's a type 1 thingy you add a 1 to 1 link to the relevant table. The business functions around type 1 only need to write to that table, never the entity table.

A possibility anyway.